# Low frame rate in video editor preview

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Apologies if this is a duplicate post, but nothing I've read on any of the others has worked. I've imported various video (recorded at 30 fps) and audio strips into Blender's video editor and when trying to preview the result, the fps drops to 5-10 fps, making aligning the video and audio impossible.

I've tried:

- Playing the videos through a few times
- Installing the latest graphics drivers (already installed)
- Increasing the memory cache limit in system preferences
- Giving Blender high priority in task manager
- Lowering the output resolution (helps but is unusable)
- Changing the sync mode to frame dropping and AV-sync
- Trying different output video codecs

I'm using Blender v2.79 on Windows 10 x64 and importing .mov video files and .wav audio files.

Thanks.

Comment: Create proxies and generate timecode for each strip then edit in proxy mode.

Comment: What's the video resolution, video codec, color encoding format?

Comment: https://youtu.be/0s_GoWn1YGU The frame rate in editor preview has no impact on rendered video frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure Blender is using the same resolution as your input video in the timeline.

[image]

If you're still slow, then it's probably time to generate proxy files. You're probably trying to edit a compressed video type instead of a RAW video type. By making proxy files, you get around this issue.

Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZl1xS9Lmvw) on how to generate proxy files.